# Java datePicker - How to set default date in JTextfield

Tags: user-interface, datepicker

Im using a DatePicker as part of a form. What i would like is for todays date to be in the JTexfield thats with the JDatePicker when the form opens.

If i use :

```
            UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
    model.setDate(2014, 06, 06);
    JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
    JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel);
```

All it does is set the date in the popup box. What i need it to do is be on the form as soon as it opens

I want it to be like this when its first opened.

[image]

But its like this

[image]

Found the answer.

Ue the method

```
model.setSelected(true);
```

After setting the initial time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method

```
model.setSelected(true);
```

After setting the initial time.

Comment: @SarpKaya First you need to write: model.setDate(2014, 06, 06); and then write: model.setSelected(true); and it will work